# How to do a custom export from oracle webcenter content (ucm)?

Tags: oracle, content-management-system, webcenter, oracle-ucm

I am working with oracle webcenter content (WCC) aka UCM, and i need to do a custom export, similar to single revision replication.
I can't use single revision replication since it is bugged on my UCM server version (11.1.1.8.0) and the destiny server may already have multiple revisions of that file.
So i've tried to replicate the query generated by the preview option on the archiver applet when i select single revision replication.
For each unique content id i need to export only the most recent revision that matches the query, so i've tried the following:

```
Revisions.dID IN (select max (REV22.dID) from Revisions REV22, DocMeta,
Documents where REV22.dID = Documents.dID and REV22.dID = DocMeta.dID and
Documents.dlsPrimary <> 0 AND REV22.dReleaseState <> 'E' and
REV22.dReleaseState <> 'N' and  (

xCollectionID <> 0 and (
Revisions.dDocName like 'ABCD%' or
) and (
 (dInDate BETWEEN {ts '2017-11-10 12:00:00.000'} AND {ts '2017-11-10 17:00:00.000'})
))
and REV22.dRevClassID = Revisions.dRevClassID)
```

But it doesn't work, the WCC throw the following error on preview:

[image: WCC error]

**Server Log:**

> !csUserEventMessage,weblogic,YYYY!$!csServiceDataException,GET_DATARESULTSET,createResultSetSQL!$!csJdbcGenericError
>   intradoc.common.ServiceException:
>   !csServiceDataException,GET_DATARESULTSET,createResultSetSQL!$
>   *ScriptStack GET_DATARESULTSET 3:createResultSetSQL,**no captured values**
>           at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.buildServiceException(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:2173)
>           at intradoc.server.Service.buildServiceException(Service.java:2402)
>           at intradoc.server.Service.createServiceExceptionEx(Service.java:2396)
>           at intradoc.server.Service.createServiceException(Service.java:2391)
>           at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.handleActionException(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1816)
>           at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doAction(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1766)
>           at intradoc.server.Service.doAction(Service.java:564)
>           at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doActions(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1483)
>           at intradoc.server.Service.doActions(Service.java:559)
>           at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.executeActions(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1415)
>           at intradoc.server.Service.executeActions(Service.java:545)
>           at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doRequest(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:751)
>           at intradoc.server.Service.doRequest(Service.java:1974)
>           at intradoc.server.ServiceManager.processCommand(ServiceManager.java:486)
>           at intradoc.server.IdcServerThread.processRequest(IdcServerThread.java:265)
>           at intradoc.idcwls.IdcServletRequestUtils.doRequest(IdcServletRequestUtils.java:1355)
>           at intradoc.idcwls.IdcServletRequestUtils.processFilterEvent(IdcServletRequestUtils.java:1732)
>           at intradoc.idcwls.IdcIntegrateWrapper.processFilterEvent(IdcIntegrateWrapper.java:223)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor265.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at idcservlet.common.IdcMethodHolder.invokeMethod(IdcMethodHolder.java:87)
>           at idcservlet.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodEx(ClassHelperUtils.java:305)
>           at idcservlet.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodWithArgs(ClassHelperUtils.java:278)
>           at idcservlet.ServletUtils.executeContentServerIntegrateMethodOnConfig(ServletUtils.java:1680)
>           at idcservlet.IdcFilter.doFilter(IdcFilter.java:457)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
>           at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
>           at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>           at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221) Caused by: intradoc.data.DataException: !csJdbcGenericError
>           at intradoc.jdbc.JdbcWorkspace.handleSQLException(JdbcWorkspace.java:2595)
>           at intradoc.jdbc.JdbcWorkspace.createResultSetSQL(JdbcWorkspace.java:830)
>           at intradoc.jdbc.JdbcWorkspace.createResultSetSQL(JdbcWorkspace.java:769)
>           at intradoc.server.Service.createResultSetSQL(Service.java:3742)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6893.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at intradoc.common.IdcMethodHolder.invokeMethod(IdcMethodHolder.java:86)
>           at intradoc.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodEx(ClassHelperUtils.java:310)
>           at intradoc.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethod(ClassHelperUtils.java:295)
>           at intradoc.server.Service.doCodeEx(Service.java:637)
>           at intradoc.server.Service.doCode(Service.java:592)
>           at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doAction(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1693)
>           ... 48 more

**Archiver Log:**

> Event generated by user 'XXXX' at host 'YYYY'. Edited properties for
>   archive 'AAAA' in collection 'BBBB'. Updated values: aExportQuery =
>   Standard Query ValuePanel UseExportDate 0 AllowExportPublished 0
>   AllRevisions 1 LatestRevisions 0 NotLatestRevisions 0
>   MostRecentMatching 0 CurrentIndex 1 Clauses
>   xCollectionID:numberNotEquals:0,dDocName:sqlEq:CCCC CustomQuery
>   Revisions.dID%IN%(select%max%(REV22.dID)%from%Revisions%REV22,%DocMeta,
>   Documents%where%REV22.dID%=%Documents.dID%and%REV22.dID%=%DocMeta.dID%and
>   Documents.dlsPrimary%<>%0%AND%REV22.dReleaseState%<>%'E'%and
>   REV22.dReleaseState%<>%'N'%and%%(
>
> xCollectionID%<>%0%and%( Revisions.dDocName%like%'ABCD#%'%or )%and%(
>   %(dInDate%BETWEEN%{ts%'2017-11-10%12:00:00.000'}%AND%{ts%'2017-11-10%17:00:00.000'})
>   )) and%REV22.dRevClassID%=%Revisions.dRevClassID) IsCustom 1.

**System Audit Log**

> systemdatabase/6  11.16 09:40:37.958  IdcServer-248219    Reusing connection retrieved from external pool.
>   systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.959  IdcServer-248219    !csMonitorActiveDbConnections,1
>   systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.959  IdcServer-248219    Assigned connection to this thread, took 8.32 ms.  connect
>   systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.959  IdcServer-248219    !csMonitorReadActions,1008597
>   systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.968  IdcServer-248219    !csMonitorReadActions,1008598
>   systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    1.81 ms. SELECT 1 FROM DUAL[Executed. Returned row(s): true]
>   systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    !csDbUnableToCreateResultSet,SELECT Revisions.*\, DocMeta.*\, Documents.*\, RevClasses.*
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            FROM Revisions\, DocMeta\, Documents\, RevClasses
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            WHERE Revisions.dID = Documents.dID
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            AND Revisions.dID = DocMeta.dID
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            AND Revisions.dRevClassID = RevClasses.dRevClassID
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            AND Documents.dIsPrimary <> 0
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            AND Revisions.dReleaseState <> 'E' AND Revisions.dStatus <> 'DELETED'
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219         AND ((((((((Revisions.dID IN (select max (REV22.dID) from Revisions REV22\, DocMeta\,
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    Documents where REV22.dID = Documents.dID and REV22.dID = DocMeta.dID and
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    Documents.dlsPrimary <> 0 AND REV22.dReleaseState <> 'E' and
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    REV22.dReleaseState <> 'N' and  (
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    xCollectionID <> 0 and (
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    Revisions.dDocName like 'ABCD%' or
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    ) and (
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219     (dInDate BETWEEN {ts '2017-11-10 12:00:00.000'} AND {ts '2017-11-10 17:00:00.000'})
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    ))
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    and REV22.dRevClassID = Revisions.dRevClassID)) AND (Revisions.dPublishState is null OR Revisions.dPublishState = '')))))))) ORDER by Revisions.dDocName!$ORA-00936: missing expression
>
> systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    run: 1.96 ms.  total 5.64 ms. [ORA-00936: missing expression
>    systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    ]
>   services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    !csUserEventMessage,aaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb!$ intradoc.common.ServiceException: !csServiceDataException,GET_DATARESULTSET,createResultSetSQL!$
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    *ScriptStack GET_DATARESULTSET
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    3:createResultSetSQL,**no captured values**
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.buildServiceException(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:2173)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.Service.buildServiceException(Service.java:2402)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.Service.createServiceExceptionEx(Service.java:2396)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.Service.createServiceException(Service.java:2391)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.handleActionException(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1816)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doAction(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1766)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.Service.doAction(Service.java:564)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doActions(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1483)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.Service.doActions(Service.java:559)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.executeActions(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1415)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.Service.executeActions(Service.java:545)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doRequest(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:751)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.Service.doRequest(Service.java:1974)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.ServiceManager.processCommand(ServiceManager.java:486)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.IdcServerThread.processRequest(IdcServerThread.java:265)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.idcwls.IdcServletRequestUtils.doRequest(IdcServletRequestUtils.java:1355)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.idcwls.IdcServletRequestUtils.processFilterEvent(IdcServletRequestUtils.java:1732)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.idcwls.IdcIntegrateWrapper.processFilterEvent(IdcIntegrateWrapper.java:223)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor265.invoke(Unknown Source)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at idcservlet.common.IdcMethodHolder.invokeMethod(IdcMethodHolder.java:87)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at idcservlet.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodEx(ClassHelperUtils.java:305)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at idcservlet.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodWithArgs(ClassHelperUtils.java:278)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at idcservlet.ServletUtils.executeContentServerIntegrateMethodOnConfig(ServletUtils.java:1680)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at idcservlet.IdcFilter.doFilter(IdcFilter.java:457)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219    Caused by: intradoc.data.DataException: !csJdbcGenericError
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.jdbc.JdbcWorkspace.handleSQLException(JdbcWorkspace.java:2595)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.jdbc.JdbcWorkspace.createResultSetSQL(JdbcWorkspace.java:830)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.jdbc.JdbcWorkspace.createResultSetSQL(JdbcWorkspace.java:769)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.Service.createResultSetSQL(Service.java:3742)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6893.invoke(Unknown Source)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.common.IdcMethodHolder.invokeMethod(IdcMethodHolder.java:86)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodEx(ClassHelperUtils.java:310)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethod(ClassHelperUtils.java:295)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.Service.doCodeEx(Service.java:637)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.Service.doCode(Service.java:592)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doAction(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1693)
>    services/3 11.16 09:40:37.970  IdcServer-248219            ... 48 more
>   systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.973  IdcServer-248219    !csMonitorActiveDbConnections,0
>   systemdatabase/6   11.16 09:40:37.973  IdcServer-248219    release pool connection

Comment: Open Administration - System Audit Information. Add systemdatabase to Active Sections. Do your export again, and then find the relevant parts of Server Output. Post them here.

Comment: I've added waht you have requested

Comment: You posted parts of the log, but that is not the place you want to look at now. On the System Audit Information Page, there is a View System Out close to the top. Use Clear just before your export attempt, and Refresh directly after.

Comment: Added system audit log

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your systemdatabase trace you will find two select statements. The first one you can ignore. The second one is what is giving you the problem. It is composed from a standard statement, together with your additions.
If you extract this select statement from the trace and try run it in SQL Developer, you'll find that there is something missing here:

```
Revisions.dDocName like 'ABCD%' or )
```